# My bathroom’s baseboard heater will not shut off

Tags: bathroom, heater

I live in an older townhouse that has been updated but the heating system is still wall units in each room controlled by a wall thermostat. However in the bathroom it’s a baseboard heater that is controlled by a turning knob on the front side of the unit. I used it once during a snow and ice storm a while ago, I turned it off and gave it no thought, but now it’s been warmer and I noticed it was hot in the bathroom, I felt around the heater and heat is coming out still but I shut it off, so it’s just continuously running at a low ish temp but still high enough to feel it and be uncomfortably hot. My electric bill has been higher and then I find out this thing has been running all this time. How do I shut it off? I looked in the breaker box and it’s not listed as one of the switches. I’m at a loss and I’m super hot.
I’m nervous to leave and it be electrical and a fire start or something.

Comment: The unit has failed. If you are not comfortable with disconnecting the electric to the unit, you have no choice but to call an electrician.  We cannot help you any further as you have not provided any details about the heater.

Answer (score 2):

The thermostat (inside the unit connected to the knob) has likely failed. Or maybe you just didn't turn it OFF hard enough. The controlling breaker is not necessarily marked correctly, so you could enlist the help of a friend to stand by the breaker box and turn each one off sequentially until the one turning off the heater is found. This should be obvious if you turn the heater way up while doing this. Then it's just a matter of finding a replacement thermostat for your unit, and finding someone able and willing to change it out.

Comment: Might be less ambigious to shut off all the dual-pole breakers, wait for it to cool down, and then look for the one that makes it hot when you turn it on.